# Why do Power Bi freezes when saving a measure?

Tags: powerbi

I practiced to learn Power Bi. I have a data model of size 180931 bytes. I clicked Modelling/New Measure and the put formula `Measure 2 = [Kumulatiivinen myynti €]*2`. Now if I'm able to edit the formula, put the formula and try to save, the Power Bi freezes. Is there a fix for this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this doesnt work. Normally you should get this error message:

[image]

The problem is a measure returns a single (scalar) value but your formula is row wise.
Your formula will work in the query editor (M), if you add a custom column with this expression. In the query editor you work row wise.

```
'M expression
= [Column1] * 2
```

The result will be a new column where every row has twice the value.

In a measure the correct expression would either be (for all rows):

```
'DAX new measure expression
= Sum([Kumulatiivinen myynti €]) * 2
```

or you dont add a measure (you have to add instead a new column), then you can use this expression:

```
'DAX new column expression
= Sumx('YourTable', 'YourTable'[Kumulatiivinen myynti €] * 2)
```

which is the same result as the M expression.

Comment: I see. I was wondering is there a way to prevent freezing but instead it will give an error message.